# store variable in application scope java glassfish

Tags: java, web-services, variables, scope, glassfish-3

i'm trying to store a number in the applicationscope of a glassfish webservice

the webservice:

```
@WebService()
public class datacheck {
    //TODO 080 disable sql_log in the settings of hibernate
    //TODO 090 check todo's from webservice_1

    private int counter = 5;
```

when i request the counter variable i get 5
and

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "increaseCounter")
public Integer increaseCounter() {
    counter++;
    return counter;
}
```

returns 6 but
when i try to do this afterwards i get 5 again:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getCounter")
public Integer getCounter() {
    return counter;
}
```

how do i store a variable that is available for all methods in the webservice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your use case and architecture to an extent. If every user should see the result of increment counter then yo could declare it statically in your code.

```
private static int counter = 5;
```

This will only work if you have only one JVM in your application though and would require careful thought about synchronization.

Alternatively you could persist it externally ( to a database or file for example )

Comment: thx, thats what i was looking for. i'll try this and take in account possible sync problems.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern should work. you will end up with the same instance in the whole JVM. Beware though: writing to a singleton from different threads might be a contented lock, and that way be dragons!

There's also [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) if you want to constraint an object to one thread (i think glassfish is one thread per request but dont cite me :)